# Number of input split remains 1, While using DBInputFormat to read Records from Oracle Database using Hadoop 2.7.3

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce, mapper

I am new to hadoop. I have a confusion in allocating the input split for reading records from a table in oracle database. I have tried,

`Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize","<size in bytes>");
conf.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize","<size in bytes>");`

and,

```
job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapred.map.tasks",<number of map tasks>);
```

and even,

```
JobConf jobcon = new JobConf(conf,MyDBtoHdfsClass.class);
jobcon.setNumMapTasks(<number of map tasks>);
```

But none works while I use them in case of reading records from database.
I have created a table with

> 1,00,000 records consisting of a unique 
>   numeric key (1 to 100,000) as the primary key followed by a numeric value in the second field.

and whatever input split limit I set, it only creats a single split.

However when I run a simple wordcount program, the input split works perfectly.

I dont know why, and when I googled this problem, i found a similar question asked by Dan Harvey, which I am attaching here.

http://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/general/104dnx4yq0/dbinputformat-number-of-mappers

Please help me to clear the doubt.

(I am using Eclipse IDE for testing)

[image]

Comment: Does the jobtracker also show 1 map task being executed for the import job you are running ?

Comment: Have you set the execution engine to MapReduce in your script? It isn't explicitly stated and just wanted to check :)

Comment: @Amit Yes. Let me add the screenshot for you. I am now working in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Fredulom How do I set that? Other programs are working fine (say wordcount ).

Comment: Wait a second, are you writing a Java application that directly leverages the MapReduce classes? In which case, you won't need to set an execution engine, I couldn't tell whether you were using something like Scala which you can set the execution engine for, apologies :)

Comment: Have you tried checking the job configuration and counters using Jobtracker. You have got a job id in the log which can be used to locate job you are running on the hadoop cluster.